# CSS Is it possible to adjust the width of the div to equal to/grater than the content in ::before?

Tags: css

I want both div and div::before to have the same width but sometimes div::before's content is longer than the content in div, so it ends up being in 2 lines instead. Is there any way that I can make this flexible? Like the width of these two elements will be equal to the maximum width among them. To be more specific, I am trying to make a box with some text below another text.

Here is what I have for div and its::before

```
div
{
   position: relative;
}
div::before{
   background-color: yellow;
   top: 15px;
   text-align: center;
   content: 'something';
   position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: please add your HTML

Comment: to achieve this you need to first get rid of position:absolute, otherwise it won't be possible